# Insert table in foreign key with multiple value MS SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, multiple-inheritance

How do i insert multiple value on the TelephoneNo since Client may have multiple telephone number?

```
CREATE TABLE Telephone
(TelephoneID tinyint Primary key,
TelephoneNo int)
```

and..

```
CREATE TABLE CLIENT
(ClientID smallint Primary key,
FName varchar(25),
LName varchar(25),
HomeAddress varchar(50),
TelephoneID tinyint foreign key references Telephone(TelephoneID))
```

so that it can be viewed like this

```
ClientID | FName | LName | HomeAddress | TelephoneID
C-01       Harry   Sendon   1333 Cali.    1,2
C-02       Pierre  Ferrer   1515 LasV.     3

TelephoneID | Telephone
    1          7894561
    2          8945612
    3          7569696
```

that's all i can explain. xD

Answer (score 3):

CREATE TABLE CLIENT
(ClientID smallint Primary key,
FName varchar(25),
LName varchar(25),
HomeAddress varchar(50))

CREATE TABLE Telephone
(TelephoneID tinyint Primary key,
TelephoneNo int,
ClientID smallint foreign key references CLIENT(ClientID))

ClientID | FName | LName | HomeAddress

C-01       Harry   Sendon   1333 Cali.

C-02       Pierre  Ferrer   1515 LasV.

TelephoneID | Telephone | ClientID

```
1          7894561     C-01
2          8945612     C-01
3          7569696     C-02
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the wrong setup. At the moment, each client links to one telephone id. But you want to have each client having multiple telephone ids.

I would instead have:

```
CREATE TABLE Telephone
(TelephoneID tinyint Primary key,
ClientId smallint foreign key references CLIENT(ClientId),
TelephoneNo int)

CREATE TABLE CLIENT
(ClientID smallint Primary key,
FName varchar(25),
LName varchar(25),
HomeAddress varchar(50))
```

From that, it's easy to see how multiple telephone entries can relate to one client.

To get the user details and phone numbers from this do:

```
SELECT CLIENT.ClientID, CLIENT.FName, CLIENT.LName,
  CLIENT.HomeAddress, Telephone.TELEPHONEID 
FROM CLIENT
JOIN TELEPHONE ON Telephone.ClientId = CLIENT.ClientId
```

To get the telephone ids as a list:

```
SELECT CLIENT.ClientID, CLIENT.FName, CLIENT.LName,
  CLIENT.HomeAddress, GROUP_CONCAT(Telephone.TELEPHONEID)
FROM CLIENT
JOIN TELEPHONE ON Telephone.ClientId = CLIENT.ClientId
GROUP BY Client.ClientId
```

Comment: @
Sorry guys, i put it the wrong way.

all of you are correct. my bad :(
now i would like to know how to view it like this:

    ClientID | FName | LName | HomeAddress | TelephoneID
    C-01       Harry   Sendon   1333 Cali.    1,2
    C-02       Pierre  Ferrer   1515 LasV.     3
    
in sql so that i can manage to display it in listview in VB.

Comment: Gotcha. Updated again.

Comment: 'GROUP_CONCAT' is not a recognized built-in function name. :((

Comment: Sorry, you'd tagged MySql but actually I see you're on SQL Server. You can download User-defined Aggregates for SQL Server including GROUP_CONCAT from here: https://groupconcat.codeplex.com/ There's no built-in equivalent, so the alternative to adding a UDA for it is a more complex solution using temporary tables or defining your own function.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your question in the right way, you want to be able to give a client more than one telephone number.

You have to think about your table structure. Now you have a 1 to n relation from Telephone to  CLIENT. But you need a 1 to n relation from CLIENT to Telephone to give a Client multiple telephone numbers.

Your solution would be this:

```
CREATE TABLE Telephone
(TelephoneID tinyint Primary key,
TelephoneNo int,
ClientID smallint foreign key references CLIENT(ClientID))

CREATE TABLE CLIENT
(ClientID smallint Primary key,
FName varchar(25),
LName varchar(25),
HomeAddress varchar(50))
```

Now you can give multiple telephone numbers the same ClientID.